# How to create an instance method in Loopback that can access itself?

Tags: methods, instance, loopbackjs, strongloop

In one of my LoopBack models I want to add an instance method to a model, but it won't let me access the `this`, as `this` is undefined inside the prototype method:

```
module.exports = (MyModel) => {
  MyModel.prototype.doStuff = () => {
    console.log(this);  // outputs undefined
  }
}
```

This obviously limits the usefulness of a instance method.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're using [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

> An **arrow function** expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and **does not bind its own `this`**, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`.

when you rewrite it to `function(){}` you'll get access to the model's instance.